# Induction proof for $V - E + F = 2$ (Connected planar graphs)

Tags: graph-theory, induction, planar-graphs

This might be a bit of a silly question, but I'm struggling to understand this proof for $V - E + F = 2$, where $V$ = number of vertices, $E =$ number of edges and $F = $ number of faces.

I understand the first part, but I'm confused as to why we can assume true for a number of faces but then *subtract* from $F$, if we've proved it for $F = 1$.

[image]

An explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What text does the quoted proof come from?

Comment: My course notes, so I can't share the link - I just have no one to ask for help with the current situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an easy to picture example, consider the [complete graph on 4 vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#/media/File:CGK4PLN.svg). Initially $F=3, V=4, E=6.$ Notice that $V-E+F=2$. Now imagine removing the edge joining the bottom-left vertex to the center vertex (this edge is appropriate because the proof requires us to remove an edge that belongs to a cycle.) How has the picture changed? We haven't removed any vertices, so $V=4$ still. We have removed one edge, so our new $E=5$. We have also combined two faces into 1 new face, so now there are two remaining, so our new  $F=2$. Notice that it is still the case that $V-E+F=2$.

The idea is that this is what will always happen when you remove an edge that belongs to a cycle in a planar graph - doing so will reduce the number of edges and the number of faces both by 1, so the value of $V-E+F$ will not change. In this way, the author is reducing the problem for a graph with $n$ faces to a graph with $n-1$ faces. They are saying that because the value of $V-E+F$ is the same in each case, and we have assumed in the $n-1$ case that $V-E+F=2$, we have shown that the same is true in the case with $n$ faces.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. So is the idea that if we remove an edge that isn't part of a cycle, the number of vertices decreases by one and the result still holds? Why do we have to prove it for n = 1? Would we not need to prove it holds for all Kn instead?

Comment: There certainly are other ways that you could remove edges from the graph, such as removing one that isn't part of a cycle. However, the author is doing induction on the number of faces. The structure of the proof is: 1. The statement is true for graphs with 1 face. 2. If the statement is true for graphs with $n-1$ faces, it is also true for graphs with $n$ faces. 3. Therefore, the statement is true for graphs with any number of faces.

Comment: Oh man, I've just realised I completely misread the proof. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy I could help!

Comment: The statement "when you remove an edge from a planar graph - doing so will reduce the number of edges and the number of faces both by 1" is not true unless the edge we are removing belongs to a cycle. Clearly, a planar graph may have a bridge and removal of bridges do not change the number of faces. That is the reason why the proof only considers edges that belong to a cycle.

Comment: @ArsenBerk Thanks for pointing that out, I edited my answer to be a bit more precise.